# Jquery Range Slider Handle css is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

in my jsp page having 2 range sliders. one is  Filter by Result based on TIME(0-24 hrs), another one is filter Result based on FARE(0,1000). i am using jquery UI slider. I want different/separate  slider handle for each slider. i changed css but the second slider handle overwriting first slider handle? how can i achieve separate handles? my code is here [my Sample code][1]: http://jsfiddle.net/hari034/ypAdf/ . i am using query.ui.core.js,jquery.ui.widget.js,jquery.ui.mouse.js,uery.slider.js,query-ui-custom.css files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can style them diferently using a different div wrapping

### html

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" nowrap="nowrap">
    <div class="timesliderwrap">
       <div id="track6" class="...">
      <a id="track_time" style="..." href="#"></a>
     </div>
   </div>
 </td>
</tr>
 <!--Slider For Filter By Fare-->
 <tr valign="top">
    <td colspan="2">
       <div class="faresliderwrap">
          <div id="track7" class="..." style="...">
            <a id="track_price"  style="left: 0%;" class="..." href="#"></a>
          </div>
       </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

### CSS

```
.timesliderwrap .ui-slider-horizontal-time .ui-state-default {background:url(images/time_indicator1.gif) no-repeat scroll 50% 50%;}

.faresliderwrap .ui-slider-horizontal-price .ui-state-default {background:url(images/price_indicator1.gif) no-repeat scroll 50% 50%;}
```